# Permission Error при попытке удалить файл

Tags: python, файлы, path

Проблема при удалении файла, Ошибка- PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Пытался сделать это разными способами , но каждый раз приходил к одной и той же ошибки
помогите решить мою проблему

```
    for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=open(f'{file}', 'rb'))
    for file in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
        context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, video=open(f'{file}', 'rb'), supports_streaming=True)
    path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), f"{text}-stories")
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Comment: В папке path открыт какой-то файл и поэтому не может быть удален.

Comment: @Эникейщик А можно уточнить, что мне нужно исправить. просто f"{text}-stories" это тот файл, который я удаляю, я нашел этот способ и интернете, и толком не понимаю как это работает

Comment: Ничего не надо исправлять. Нужно закрыть тот самый файл. Еще возможная причина причина (хотя по сути та же самая) - сам скрипт лежит в папке path, тогда его нужно перенсти в другое место.